# How to send jpeg.Encode image?

Tags: image, http, go, multipart

I am creating a picture using jpeg.Encode and want to send it. How can I avoid creating an intermediate file?

Create and save file.

```
  // ...
  outFile, err := os.Create("./images/" + name + ".jpg")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    os.Exit(-1)
  }
  defer outFile.Close()
  buff := bufio.NewWriter(outFile)

  err = jpeg.Encode(buff, background, &jpeg.Options{Quality: 90})
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    os.Exit(-1)
  }

  err = buff.Flush()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    os.Exit(-1)
  }
```

Send file.

```
  file, err := os.Open("./images/" + name + ".jpg")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  body := &bytes.Buffer{}
  writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

  part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("photo", file.Name())
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  io.Copy(part, file)
  if err = writer.Close(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  resp, err := http.Post(uploadURL, writer.FormDataContentType(), body)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  defer resp.Body.Close()
```

How can I send a photo without saving it on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the `part` target to `jpeg.Encode()`:

```
// ...

part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("photo", file.Name())
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

err = jpeg.Encode(part, background, &jpeg.Options{Quality: 90})
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
if err = writer.Close(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

resp, err := http.Post(uploadURL, writer.FormDataContentType(), body)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Comment: I tried, but it does not work. An empty photo field comes to the server
```
        body := &bytes.Buffer{}
        writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
        defer writer.Close()

        part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("photo", photo.Name())
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("%s", err)
 }

 err = jpeg.Encode(part, background, &jpeg.Options{Quality: 90})
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
  os.Exit(-1)
 }

 resp, err = http.Post(req.Response.UploadURL, writer.FormDataContentType(), body)
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("%s", err)
 }
 defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Comment: @ИринаВоробьёва Yes, I forgot to close `writer`. See edited answer.